# iTextSharp last version doesnot support metadata?

Tags: itext

`Console.WriteLine("Chapter 1 example 6: Meta Information");`

```
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();

        try
        {
            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("Chap0106.pdf", FileMode.Create));

            // step 3: we add some metadata and open the document
            document.AddTitle("Hello World example");
            document.AddSubject("This example explains step 6 in Chapter 1");
            document.AddKeywords("Metadata, iText, step 6, tutorial");
            document.AddCreator("My program using iText#");
            document.AddAuthor("Bruno Lowagie");
            document.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
            document.Open();

            // step 4: we add a paragraph to the document
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.Close();
```

I am just copy the iTextSharp.tutorial.
I get the pdf file Chap0106.pdf but metadata show nothing...

I am use vs2008 xp system

Comment: That really ought to work. What version of iText are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the same example, and it seemed to work just fine. Your code matches up with mine as well. Make sure you are going to File > Properties within adobe reader.